# Running composer dump-env prod through ansible composer module

Tags: symfony, ansible, composer-php

I am unable to run [symfony flex](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-flex-1-2) command `composer dump-env prod` using ansible composer module. I wonder if its even possible ? My task looks sth like this:

```
- name: Composer dump env for production
  composer:
      command: dump-env
      working_dir: "{{ app_composer_package_dir }}"
      arguments: prod
  become_user: "{{app_apache_user}}"
  become: yes
```

The error I get is:

> "stderr": "\n
>   \n  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>   \n  There are no commands defined \"dump-env\".
>   \n

ansible verbose logs:

```
fatal: [testhost.com]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "apcu_autoloader": false,
            "arguments": "prod",
            "classmap_authoritative": false,
            "command": "dump-env",
            "executable": null,
            "global_command": false,
            "ignore_platform_reqs": false,
            "no_dev": true,
            "no_plugins": false,
            "no_scripts": false,
            "optimize_autoloader": true,
            "prefer_dist": false,
            "prefer_source": false,
            "working_dir": "/var/www/source"
        }
    },
    "msg": "[Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\CommandNotFoundException] Command \"dump-env\" is not defined. help [--xml] [--format FORMAT] [--raw] [--] [<command_name>]"
}
                                                          ",
```

I tried ansible `command` module to directly run the command but I get same error.

However, I am able run the command by sshing to remote (centos) instance :

```
sudo -u apache composer dump-env prod
```

> Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
>   Successfully dumped .env files in .env.local.php

Comment: Are you sure both commands run in the same working dir? Have you tried dumping `app_composer_package_dir` to check if it matches the one you were using when ssh-ing onto the host?

Comment: @dbrumann please check verbose logs

Comment: Are there any other composer steps after this one that will be executed? Maybe `composer install` is called afterwards. When symfony/flex is not yet installed, this would explain why the command is missing before, but available afterwards when you ssh in and run the command?

Comment: @dbrumann composer install runs before this step and it runs as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I am unable to run `composer dump-env prod` command using ansible composer module. However following task using ansible command module runs successfully e.g

```
- name: Composer dump env for production
  command: "{{composer_install_path}}  --working-dir={{ app_composer_package_dir }} dump-env prod"
  become_user: "{{app_apache_user}}"
  become: yes
```

which translates to sth:

`sudo -u apache /usr/local/bin/composer --working-dir=/var/www/source dump-env prod`

Comment: This was a great help, we found this to be the same for us after updating to Symfony 4 and having to update our deployment scripts. Cheers!